# Accelerate the loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that comes probably from a pivot table, so it looks quite messy. It is not just an XY 2 dimension data, but a 4 or 5.

What I am trying to do is, if certain conditions are fulfilled, then add a new column and compute the YoY change starting from row 3 (row 0,1,2 are strings).

And in order to avoid the zero division error (I'll get errors if do the math directly) when computing, I have to add loops in loops (`if` `else` function to input 0 first). By using `time()` function, I can tell that the program takes me almost 10 mins every time running it.

I wonder if there is any way smarter to program it. Appreciate your kind advice!

```py
for i in range(1, 187):
   k = i * 1000
   if df.iloc[1, i] == df.iloc[1, i - 1] and df.iloc[1, i] != df.iloc[1, i+ 1]:
        df[k] = 0
        a = df.columns.get_loc[k]
        df.iloc[0, a] = df.iloc[0, i]
        df.iloc[1, a] = df.iloc[1, i]
        df.iloc[2, a] = 'YoY%'
        
        for m in range(3, 13259):
            if df.iloc[m, i - 1] == 0:
                 df.iloc[m, a] = 0
            else:
                 df.iloc[m, a] = (df.iloc[m, i] - df.iloc[m, i - 1]) / df.iloc[m, i - 1]
df = df.sort_values(by=[0, 1, 2], axis=1)
```

The fragment of the data frame before sorting would look like this:

```
0      cash    cash    cash     cash     trade   trade    cash    cash    trade
1      54100   54100   54103    54103    52209   52209    54100   54103   52209
2      02-21   03-21   02-21    03-21    02-21   03-21    YoY%    YoY%    YoY%
3      0       0       1500     1500     -28.1   -2476.8  0       0       87.14 
4      0       500     16500    16500    25      35       0       0       0.4
5      0       0       300      600      3.1     420      0       1       134.5
       ..      ..      ..       ..       ..      ..       ..      ..      ..
13258  1973.7  4484.9  18300    18600    0       750      1.3     0.02    0
```

Comment: Can you add a small sample of your dataframe?  `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: Hi Sharma, I've updated a fragment of the sample. I'm trying not to make the data frame too complicated. Thanks!

Comment: The big advantage of data frames and pandas is that you can do matrix-wide operations with one line and don’t need to use nested loops to iterate over everything. I’d say avoid those one-by-one operations at all cost. I’d make a new frame that is only the numbers without the header strings, then another that is all the values shifted (i-l) maybe make the zeroes in the I-1 matrix NAs and do your math in one step on the entire matrices superimposed without checking for zeroes. You can also use indices to pull out all non-zero values and then do operations on just those portions of the matrix.

Comment: this dataframe fragment seems to be the result of the loop, not the input data. is that correct? i couldn't get the loop to run successfully using this sample dataframe. it's hard to optimize the loop without having the input data.

Comment: If the code is correct, but needs improvement, [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes, I know that doing matrix-wide operation is the key to speed-up. I just don't know how. And yes it is the result after the last "if" & "else" function. I guess an easier question would be:  For the last if & else loop, I hope to create a column that equals "the last col in the group" divided by "the 2nd to last col in the same group" without showing Zero Division Error. I am fine with either NA or Inf value. However, simply a code like "df.iloc[m, a] = (df.iloc[m, i] - df.iloc[m, i - 1]) / df.iloc[m, i - 1]" wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a sample of your data in a format that is easy to reproduce and work with. I will try to help:

Let's assume you have the following data:

```
records = [
    ['cash','cash','cash','cash','trade','trade'],
    [54100,54100,54103,54103,52209,52209],
    ['02-21','03-21','02-21','03-21','02-21','03-21'],
    [0,0,1500,1500,-28.1,-2476.8],
    [0,500,16500,16500,25,35],
    [0,0,300,600,3.1,420],
    [1973.7,4484.9,18300,18600,0,750],
]
index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,13259]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, index=index)
```

Which produces the following DataFrame:

```
            0       1      2      3      4       5
0        cash    cash   cash   cash  trade   trade
1       54100   54100  54103  54103  52209   52209
2       02-21   03-21  02-21  03-21  02-21   03-21
3           0       0   1500   1500  -28.1 -2476.8
4           0     500  16500  16500     25      35
5           0       0    300    600    3.1     420
13259  1973.7  4484.9  18300  18600      0     750
```

It seems as if the three first rows of your data are actually table headers. We can turn them into a muliindex to take full advantage of pandas' capabilities:

```
# Set columns index from first rows
df.columns = [df.iloc[i] for i in range(3)]
# Delete first rows used for column names
df = df.iloc[3:]
```

This produces the following dataframe (notice the first three rows are now the dataframe's columns):

```
0        cash                       trade
1       54100          54103        52209
2       02-21   03-21  02-21  03-21 02-21   03-21
3           0       0   1500   1500 -28.1 -2476.8
4           0     500  16500  16500    25      35
5           0       0    300    600   3.1     420
13259  1973.7  4484.9  18300  18600     0     750
```

Now you can use pandas to group along the columns. First things first: we need a function to apply to each pair of columns when we group them. Lets say we define the following funcion to calculate the increment between two months:

```
def calculate_incr(df):
    ''' Calculates the increment between a dataframe's first two colums.
    Ignores division by zero errors.
    '''
    mask = df.iloc[:,0] != 0  # prevents divide by zero error
    return df.loc[mask].iloc[:,1] / df.loc[mask].iloc[:,0] - 1
```

We can finally group our data and calculate the increments. It is a bit tricky, because pandas doesn't seem to like grouping on several column levels, so we are going to combine the column labels first, and the split them again in later steps to combine with the original data:

```
In []: df.groupby(by=lambda l: '_'.join(map(str, l[:2])), axis=1).agg(calculate_incr)
Out[]:
       cash_54100  cash_54103  trade_52209
3             NaN    0.000000    87.142349
4             NaN    0.000000     0.400000
5             NaN    1.000000   134.483871
13259    1.272331    0.016393          NaN
```

Numbers seem to be right, but you probably want to integrate this result into your original table and replace the `NaN`s for the division by zero errors by 0s, so let's claculate the increments again, but this time prettyfied, splitting the columns into a multiindex:

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=lambda l: '_'.join(map(str, l[:2])), axis=1)
increments = {k: calculate_incr(grp) for k, grp in grouped}
increments = pd.DataFrame(increments).fillna(0)
increments.columns = increments.columns.map(lambda c: tuple([*c.split('_'), 'YoY%']))
```

Aha! This looks nicer now:

```
In []: increments
Out[]:
           cash                 trade
          54100     54103       52209
           YoY%      YoY%        YoY%
3      0.000000  0.000000   87.142349
4      0.000000  0.000000    0.400000
5      0.000000  1.000000  134.483871
13259  1.272331  0.016393    0.000000
```

It is also now easy to incorporate this results to your original data:

```
In []: result = pd.concat([df, increments], axis=1)

In []: result
Out[]:
0        cash                       trade              cash                 trade
1       54100          54103        52209             54100     54103       52209
2       02-21   03-21  02-21  03-21 02-21   03-21      YoY%      YoY%        YoY%
3           0       0   1500   1500 -28.1 -2476.8  0.000000  0.000000   87.142349
4           0     500  16500  16500    25      35  0.000000  0.000000    0.400000
5           0       0    300    600   3.1     420  0.000000  1.000000  134.483871
13259  1973.7  4484.9  18300  18600     0     750  1.272331  0.016393    0.000000
```

Finally, if you want to leave the table as in the example your provided, without headers (i.e. multiindex columns), just use this trick to reset the columns:

```
In []: result = result.columns.to_frame().T.append(result, ignore_index=True).T.reset_index(drop=True).T

In []: result
Out[]:
        0       1      2      3      4       5        6          7        8
0    cash    cash   cash   cash  trade   trade     cash       cash    trade
1   54100   54100  54103  54103  52209   52209    54100      54103    52209
2   02-21   03-21  02-21  03-21  02-21   03-21     YoY%       YoY%     YoY%
3       0       0   1500   1500  -28.1 -2476.8        0          0  87.1423
4       0     500  16500  16500     25      35        0          0      0.4
5       0       0    300    600    3.1     420        0          1  134.484
6  1973.7  4484.9  18300  18600      0     750  1.27233  0.0163934        0
```

Comment: Kudos for tackling this without input data provided, +1. BTW pandas will automatically handle divide-by-zero if you convert to float: `return df.iloc[:,1].astype(float) / df.iloc[:,0].astype(float) - 1` (or just convert the `df` to float beforehand)

Comment: Much gratitude to Jabellcu and TDY's professional advice. Honestly, I find Jabellcu's code a little hard for me, but I'll try to process it all. And I found that the astype.(float) function perfectly solved divide-by-zero problem. May I ask how come transferring the data type to float ever solve the "denominator being 0" problem, since some of the data (like [5,4]) are already float.

Comment: @alexandraudinov In jabellcu's sample df, the data types are mixed (both strings and numerics), so pandas uses dtype `object`. After converting to MultiIndex columns, the df only has numerics. Normally when you *create* a column with both `int` and `float`, pandas automatically makes the columns as `float`. However, because these columns already existed and were dtype `object`, they remain `object` and thus contain a mix of `int` and `float`. That's why an explicit `float` conversion helps here.